# Monte Carlo for uncertainty (error) propagation

Tags: statistics, error-propagation

I have been recently reading about error propagation. Different options to do that exist. Among others, linearisation of the model by representing it as first order Taylor expansion, using Bayes theorem and Monte Carlo. I am interested learning more about the last method. It can be described in a nutshell as given the model
$$
V=F(x_1, \dots, x_n),
$$
generate a number of independent random realizations of the input vector $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ feed those values to the model $F(x_1, \dots, x_n) $ and observe the mean and the variance of the outcome $V$.

Note that the model not need to be expressible in a closed analytical form. This might be for instance some code that calculates pressure drop in a heated rod bundle. In that case the governing equations are solved numerically and input variables, such as surface roughness are taken into account, as having some underlying uncertainty. This uncertainty might be propagated by running randomly sampled input values and observing the resulting spread of the output.

Unfortunately, I am a bit confused about some of the method's properties. Firstly, is it true that correlations between the input values are taken into account. i.e. the method can handle both correlated and independent input variables. I don't really understand that, since all the $x_n$ are always sampled independently.
Is it really as simple as generating random values for the inputs $x_1, \dots, x_n$ and evaluating the function that represent our model $V=F(x_1, \dots, x_n)$?

Secondly, I don't understand how many times $V$ has to be evaluated, to generate reliable mean and variance. The only thing I came up with, is to use Chebyshev's inequality applied to the sample mean and estimate how many samples need to be drawn, to reach a certain probability that the modulus of the difference between the true mean and the sample mean is less than some fraction of the variance. 
I would be grateful if someone could shed some light on these two problems.

**EDIT:**
In accordance with one of the comments, I would like to include a specific example
$$
V=\int_s^b f(x) \left(1- \left ( \frac{s}{x} \right)^m \right) dx
$$
Where $f(x)>0$ is real, differentiable function on the interval $[c,b] \in \mathbb{R}^+$, where $\mathbb{R}^+$ denotes the positive real line. The unknown variables $s$ and $m$ are normal distributed. For simplicity one could use
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
The general model tries to fit particle reaction rate, where by adjusting $s$ and $m$, the integral $V$ approaches (fits) some measured value. The question is how the uncertainty of $s$ and $m$ affects the value of $V$.

Comment: Do you mean inde _random variables_ instead of _parameters_? Or do your 'parameters' have prior dist'ns in a Bayesian context? // If you do not program correlation into your simulation of the $x_i,$ then they will be iid. // If you have a simple example to share, that would help to clarify what you are trying to do. // Probably many thousands of iterations of $V$ will be required for useful results. // The Chebyshev bound applies very generally and so is not very sharp in most specific situations. My guess is that an approachwuth Chebyshev's Ineq will be unsatisfactory for practical purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Take some formula from physics. Say some correlation for calculating pressure drop. Many variables all of them having uncertainties. Or some computer code that calculates say heat conduction. All the input parameters have uncertainty. Heat capacity, conductivity etc. In that case even no analytic expression exists. Here I don't have prior/posterior in mind but really a black box which takes input variables with uncertainties associated to them an the question is what is the uncertainty on the other end of the black box.

Comment: @BruceET as a follow-up I would like to ask whether the distribution of the input variables, reflects the distribution of the final value $V$. Say If I had rand. normal distributed input values, would the output be also random normal.

Comment: For simple linear regression the model is $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + e_i$ where $e_i \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0, \sigma).$ Within reasonable limits $e_i$ can model errors in measuring $x_i,$ as long as the residuals are normal and seem to have constant variance across the span of values of $x_i.$ (In multiple regression there can be several predictor variables $x.$ Then there is often some association among the $x$'s.) Without data and a description of a _specific_ situation, it would not be responsible to speculate how useful a regr model would be. "Some formula from physics" isn't enough.

Comment: @BruceET Thank you for your reply. Consider the integral $\int_s^b f(x)\left(1-\left(\frac{s}{x}\right)^m \right)dx$ where the unknown normal distributed parameters are $s$ and $m$. $f(x)>0,s>0,m>0$

Comment: Not a model that's familiar to me. I'll think about it. Now maybe others will take a look too. Do you mean $m$ and $s$ are unknown normal mean and SD? Or that $m$ and $s$ are independent random variables with normal distributions (and in that case negative values need to be considered)? Also is $f(x)$ a density function of some random variable?

Comment: @BruceET is it actually possible to say if $s$ and $m$, by examining the model are correlated?

Comment: I assume you intent $m$ to the mean and $s$ to be the SD of a sample chosen at random from some population. If the population is normal then $m$ and $s$ are independent random variables. If the population is _not_ normal, then $m$ and $s$ are not independent; they might or might not be uncorrelated. // Examples: if the population is exponential, then correlated; if the population is uniform, then uncorrelated, but not independent.

Comment: You say that $m$ and $s$ are normally distributed. This puzzles me: If the population is normal then the sample mean $\bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i$ is normally distributed, but neither the sample SD $S$ nor the sample variance $S^2$ is normally distributed. // If you intend $m$ and $s$ to be Bayesian parameters, then you are free to pick whatever prior distributions you want for them. Some choices will be easier to handle mathematically than others.

Comment: @BruceET hi and thank you for taking the time to answer my questions. My model fits data and as fit parameters $s,m$ are correlated. This is what really puzzles me, whether I can just sample $s,m$ from a multivariate normal taking into account the correlation matrix. It seems a simple thing to do, but whether this is true remains an open question to me.

Comment: In a Bayesian approach, you _could_ start with a prior having uncorrelated parameters. But if you believe they might be correlated, then the model for the parameters would have to include the possibility of correlation, so that the data could lead to a correlated posterior distribution. But in my view, it is best for the prior to express your best prior knowledge or opinion (incl. correlation), then let the data "nudge" the posterior distribution in the direction of the empirical facts.

Comment: @BruceET in my case I know that the parameters are correlated (fit parameters usually are). Therefore, I sample from a multivariate Gauß distribution and on the basis of this I compute my mean and variance.